# get variable from controller's dropdown selection to change another selection in an Angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 button dropdowns working, via angular-dropdowns. When I click a language selection in one dropdown, I want to change the array (with that language) that displays in the other dropdown. Things work with hardcoded changes, but not with user clicks.

Being an Angular newbie, I'm not sure if a factory is the right way, but here's my code of the moment. Array contents are shortened. The controller for language selection is:

```
residenceApp.controller('languageController', [ '$scope', 'changeLanguage',
function( $scope, changeLanguage ) {
var languageChoices = [
    {"text": "English", "val": "en"},
    {"text": "Español", "val": "es"}
];
$scope.ddMenuOptions = languageChoices;
$scope.ddMenuSelected = {};
$scope.$watch('ddMenuSelected', function(newVal) {
    if (newVal && newVal.text) {                    
        changeLanguage(newVal.val);
        //changeLanguage is a factory function that executes translate.use(langKey); to translate HTML elements. It works.
    }
}, true); //end of $scope.watch()
}]);
```

The relevant HTML for the language selection button is:

```
<div id="leftOfMap" class="floatingSection" data-ng-controller="languageController">
<ul>
<li class="leftOfMapItem"><button id="languageButton" dropdown-menu="ddMenuOptions" dropdown-model="ddMenuSelected" class="btn-menu">{{ 'LANGUAGE' | translate }}</button></li>
```

The HTML for the second button is identical, except for the id and the name on the button.

The factory with dropdown arrays in several languages looks like:

```
languageFactories.factory( 'changePostDd', [ '$translate', function( translate ) {
var ddSelections = [];
var ddSelections_en = [
{"text": "RENT:", "val": "R"},
{"text": "SELL:", "val": "S"}
];
var ddSelections_es = [
{"text": "RENTAR:", "val": "R"},
{"text": "VENDER:", "val": "S"}
];
var langKey=translate.use(); //works on page load only
    switch( langKey ) {
  case "en":
     ddSelections = ddSelections_en;
     break;
  case "es":
     ddSelections = ddSelections_es;
     break;
  default:
     console.log('There should not be a default failover.');
    }
return ddSelections;
}]);
```

Among many things, I've tried $scope in the factory, and it broke the entire page. I tried the value() method and it did not work with clicks.

The controller for the second dropdown button is very similar to the first one, except it gets its array from the factory, instead of being hardcoded in the controller.

```
residenceApp.controller('postButtonController', ['$scope', 'changePostDd',
function ($scope, ddSelections) {
    $scope.ddMenuOptions = ddSelections;
    $scope.ddMenuSelected = {};
    $scope.$watch('ddMenuSelected', function(newVal) {
      if (newVal && newVal.text) {
      // do stuff
      }
```

In short, when the Espanol selection is clicked and newVal.val is set to es, I want the factory (or whatever) to switch() in ddSelections_es. Currently, ddSelections_en goes to the second dropdown button on page load, and when click changes are made on Espanol, the factory does not change the array for display at that second button. How do I make the array of ddSelections change?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in AngularJS in the following way. I am sure you can use the same in similar widget libraries. The key here is your ng-options is chosen with

```
ddSelectionsAllLangs[languageSelected.val]
```

You may use some function on the scope as well.

```
//this is your existing code - language choices
var languageChoices = [
    {"text": "English", "val": "en"},
    {"text": "Español", "val": "es"}
];
$scope.ddMenuOptions = languageChoices;

//if you want to default to certain language 
$scope.languageSelected = languageChoices[0];


var ddSelections_en = [

{"text": "RENT:", "val": "R"},
{"text": "SELL:", "val": "S"}
];
var ddSelections_es = [
{"text": "RENTAR:", "val": "R"},
{"text": "VENDER:", "val": "S"}
];

$scope.ddSelectionsAllLangs = {
   en: ddSelections_en,
   es: ddSelections_es
}
```

Then in the HTML say this drop down menu selects the language.

```
<select ng-model="languageSelected" ng-options="lang.text for lang in   languageChoices">
 <option value="">-- choose language --</option>
</select>
```

The next drop down menu is the actual content.

```
<select ng-model="ddSelected" 
     ng-options="lang.text for lang in  ddSelectionsAllLangs[languageSelected.val]">
 </select>
```

---

Another option:- Using $rootScope.myLang instead of additional `<select>` to choose the language

```
languageFactories.factory( 'changePostDd', [ '$translate', '$rootScope', function( translate, $rootScope ) { 


var ddSelectionsAllLangs = {
   en: [
         {"text": "RENT:", "val": "R"},
         {"text": "SELL:", "val": "S"}
   ],
   es: [
         {"text": "RENTAR:", "val": "R"},
         {"text": "VENDER:", "val": "S"}
   ]
 };

var changePostDdFactory = {};

//returns an array appropriate to the language   
changePostDdFactory.getDDSelections = function() {
       return  ddSelectionsAllLangs[$rootScope.myLang]
};

return changePostDdFactory;

}]);
```

Comment: I am not able to get this to work. It may be me or the code. ddSelections is in a factory, so I put $scope.ddSelectionsAllLang there. I first get an error of $scope undefined. When I put $scope in the factory dependencies, I get Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20changePostDd   Further, your approach creates a select box. For cosmetic reasons, I prefer the button dropdown. I need a programmatic event when dropdown selection occurs to trigger selection in the factory via $rootScope - I think. Thank you,though.

Comment: If you put $scope.ddSelectionsAllLang in factory it will say undefined because $scope object that is injected in a factory is not the the same as when you have it on controller. Note "A new child scope will be available as an injectable parameter to the Controller's constructor function as $scope." as in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller.

Comment: My advise is to not go with "event based" approach because that is not the "Angular Way". If you use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown there is a directive for that and you can avoid the event based approach.

Comment: Thanks again. When $scope is undefined in the factory, it breaks the page, and when $scope is a dependency in the factory, it breaks the page. Hence my thought about $rootScope - plus some related research on this. I hear you on the "event based" approach. My quick reaction, without any research, is I should therefore set something in $rootScope inside the if(), when one of the button dropdowns is selected. Could this approach work? Also. Is it possible to use the bootstrap dropdown directive and no bootstrap styling? I don't like BS styling.

Comment: $rootScope will work. However there is a simple (and good practice solution for your problem). You can always create a public function in your factory pass in $scope from controller or other less sensitive object to that function. I feel passing/accessing any scope objects outside controllers/directives is less clean way.  `.factory('myFactory', [function(){  var myFactory = {}; myFactory.myFunction = function(someScopeInputOrOtherObjectParam) { return some result;};   return myFactory; }])`

Comment: Side point - I see that you are trying to achieve i18n,l10n - you may be interested in http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-translate.html or https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n to start with.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using angular-translate and its great. The documentation is excellent, even for a newbie like me. It handles lots of 'special situations' easily, like remembering the users last language used, using irregular plurals (2 mice), downloading only for the page routed, etc. That part has been easy. This tough part is communicating between 2 controllers when ng-click is not appropriate.

Comment: Halfway-maybe. In languageController (the 1st block of code above), inside the if(), I added $rootScope.newLanguage = newVal.val; It sets to es when Espanol is selected. Correct. In the changePostDd factory (3d block), I put var langKey = $rootScope.newLanguage; As best I can tell, it doesn't execute, and the second dropdown fails, though no Console errors. I put $rootScope in the factory dependencies. When hardcoded langKey = 'es'; everything works-translation selection and dropdown. How can I get the value of $rootScope.newLanguage into the Angular factory, changePostDd ?

Comment: Just to be complete, the factory function with $rootScope dependency declared starts with    languageFactories.factory( 'changePostDd', [ '$translate', '$rootScope', function( translate, $rootScope ) { //do stuff }]);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59603/discussion-between-bhantol-and-mike-laird).

Comment: Added $rootScope option to my answer

Comment: No, I'm still working it. I bought a book - learned and tried a lot. Today, I got data going from the languageController to an updateLanguage factory that saves and, I think, broadcasts the data. I have to learn more about $on() to listen for / pick up the data and use it to change ddSelections in the postButtonController. Thanks for your interest. The concept has been clear for a while, but the specifics are taking a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned the effort to make a custom factory on the hunch that the $translate service in angular-translate could be made to work. It took a lot of learning about AngularJS and an embarrassing number of hours, but it finally works in 3 lines of code inside the controller's worker function.  The working code is here:

[Can't get $translate service from angular-translate to change dropdown array for ngDropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798947/cant-get-translate-service-from-angular-translate-to-change-dropdown-array-for/25874905#25874905)

bhantol, thank you for pointing me in the right direction to learn a lot.