# Can't get $translate service from angular-translate to change dropdown array for ngDropdowns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

angular-translate is working to change my HTML. I have an array of selection items for the ngDropdown button directive that also has to change. After changing languages, I try to get the new/current language with translate.use(). Something doesn't work.

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="postBox" class="floatingSection" data-ng-controller="postButtonController2">
  <button id="postButton" dropdown-menu="ddMenuOptions" dropdown-model="ddMenuSelected" class="btn-menu" ng-click="getCurrentLanguage()">{{ 'POST' | translate }}</button>
</div>
```

Here's the controller for that postButton. It should get the new/current language from $translate and use that string to get the dropdown selection array, ddSelections.withLangChoice  $scope.getCurrentLanguage selects the correct array when hardcoded, but not when getting variables from $translate for the language string.

Here's the controller for the button with a dropdown. Comments describe things that work and things that don't on several lines.

```
residenceApp.controller('postButtonController2', ['$translate', '$scope', 'changePostDdFactory',
function ( $translate, $scope, ddSelections ){
//ddSelections is the result object from the function returned by changePostDdFactory
  $scope.getCurrentLanguage = function( $translate ){
    alert('here I am in postButtonController2'); //fires on post button clicks and on page load
    alert('here I am in postButtonController2' + $translate.use()); //does not fire on post button clicks. fires on page load
    $scope.langKey=$translate.use(); //gets langKey in $translate on page load only
    $translate.refresh($scope.langKey);//should refresh the translation, but nothing
    alert('from postButtonController2 - currentLanguage is' + ' ' + $translate.use() ); //does not fire on button click. fires on page load
    //return 'es'; //hardcoded works on page load & sets ddSelections.withLangChoice to es array
    return $translate.use(); //sets language for ddSelections on page load, no language changes
};
$scope.ddMenuOptions = ddSelections.withLangChoice($scope.getCurrentLanguage($translate)); //works on page load, no language change occurs
$scope.ddMenuSelected = {};
//working code to watch for change from user selection
}]);
```

I'm new but, shouldn't $translate service work in a controller. Presuming that's true, what has to change to get changes to occur. I recently added ng-click to the HTML for the button, but by itself it has had no impact.

Comment: I discovered some small progress. When the 3d line of code, for $scope.getCurrenLanguage, is changed to $scope.getCurrentLanguage = function(){, then all the lines of code inside that function start executing. However, I'm not clear yet about the return statement. The problem is not solved because $scope.ddMenuOptions does not work, but its a step forward.  Can someone explain why removing $translate from the function argument (in the 3d line of code, only) allows these Angular statements to execute? This is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

I began to suspect that the 2d to last line in the OP was not executing. Lines before it executed, lines after it executed, but alerts() around it were odd. So I put that line inside the function, and it worked. Here's the revised, working code.

```
residenceApp.controller('postButtonController2', ['$translate', '$scope',  'changePostDdFactory',
function ( $translate, $scope, ddSelections ){
  var ddSelections;
  //ddSelections is the result object from the function returned by changePostDdFactory
  $scope.getCurrentLanguage = function(){
  $scope.langKey=$translate.use(); //use() as a getter
  $scope.ddMenuOptions = ddSelections.withLangChoice($scope.langKey);
  return;
};
$scope.ddMenuSelected = {};
//code to watch for change from user selection
}]);
```

I remain mystified about why $scope.getCurrentLanguage only works as an anonymous function, and why $scope.ddMenuOptions must be inside the function. But it works, and its very simple.